# How to check double v-for and if is in both then change style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, styles, v-for

```
<div v-for="memberMembershipyear in memberMembershipyears">
  <li v-for="membershipYear in membershipYears"
      :style="membershipYear.num === memberMembershipyear.num ? 'color:green' : color:red'">
         {{membershipYear.membershipType}} {{membershipYear.yr}}
  </li>
</div>
```

This is not working as I expect, showing me everything like this. Mostly are red colored, some of them are green colored. Its repeating to much time. I tried also with v-once, but it didnt work.

```
 Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
Membership of club 2001
Membership of club 2002
Membership of club 2003
Membership of club 2004
Membership of club 2006
Membership of club 2007
Membership of club 2009
Membership of club 2010
Membership of club 2012
Membership of club 2013
Membership of club 2014
Membership of club 2015
Membership of club 2017
Membership of club 2018
Membership of club 2019
Membership of club 2020
```

How do i show all memberships and just memberships that is member in should colored green? All other should colored red...

Comment: styling expects an object like {color: green}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="memberMembershipyear in memberMembershipyears">
  <li v-for="membershipYear in membershipYears"
      :style="membershipYear.num === memberMembershipyear.num ? 'color:green' : 'color:red'">
         {{membershipYear.membershipType}} {{membershipYear.yr}}
  </li>
</div>
```

can you try like that

Comment: I tried like that, but instead of 10 rows, show me 40 rows or 50 rows, depends on how many times was member in different memberships